# How to get ListView's textview for intent in ContextMenu?

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I have a ListView. This ListView has an array and the array has 5 numbers. First of all, in the first activity the user selects 5 numbers and theses 5 number go in the ListView in the second activity. I want to start an `Intent` with theses 5 numbers when the user click on any number on the Context menu. The intent will start that position. But why cant I get the selected number?

```
public class AnaMenu extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final int MENU_Ara = Menu.FIRST+1;
    int sayı = 50;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ana_menu);
        ListView liste = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.oyun);

        OyunTextView oyunTextView = new OyunTextView();
        liste.setAdapter(oyunTextView);
        registerForContextMenu(liste);
    }

    class OyunTextView extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            Intent i = getIntent();
            final ArrayList<String> secilmis = i.getStringArrayListExtra("listem");

            return secilmis.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.oyuntextview , null);
            TextView namesbox = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.isim);
            TextView sayılar = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sayı);
            Intent i = getIntent();
            final ArrayList<String> secilmis = i.getStringArrayListExtra("listem");
            namesbox.setText(secilmis.get(position));

            sayılar.setText(String.valueOf(sayı));
            if (sayı == 50) {
                sayılar.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.elli));}
                return convertView;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_Ara, Menu.NONE, "Ara");

            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

            Intent i = getIntent();
            secilmis = i.getStringArrayListExtra("listem");

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case MENU_Ara:
                    Intent ara = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);

                    ara.setData(Uri.parse());
                    startActivity(ara);
                    return true;
            }

            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.mains,menu);

            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_browse :ayar();return true;

                case R.id.backbut: geri();return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        private void ayar() {
            Intent i = new Intent(AnaMenu.this, Ayarlar.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        private void geri() {
            Intent ii = new Intent(AnaMenu.this, MainActivity.class);

            startActivity(ii);
            AnaMenu.this.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: String value=secilmis.get(info.position).toString();

Comment: It is not working.switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case MENU_Ara:
                Intent ara = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                String value=secilmis.get(info.position).toString();
ara.setData(Uri.parse(value));
                startActivity(ara); This Listview has been customized. It has 3 textviews.

Comment: can u share ur full source?

Comment: For get the items selected count (checked) use: listView.getCheckedItemCount()

Comment: I have shared all second activity. Editted now.

Comment: Okey.I solved my question, I was forget little thing. ara.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+ secilmis.get(info.position).toString())); I have forgetten to add "tel:". # Bhuvaneshwaran Vellingiri  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `arraylistname.get(position)` in the `onItemClickListener` method to get the position of the selected item.

Comment: I get it. But now a another problem.How can I get info.position out of the contextmenuselected [link] (method.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150636/how-to-update-costumized-listview-with-contextmenu-after-intent-ended/45151922?noredirect=1#comment77332045_45151922)